# $.each not updating css width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a loop, which performs an ajax call on each iteration and I want to set the progress bar updated.. But it is not updating, it goes to 100% directly when ending...

**I've tried to put the bar update call outside the success action (inside the loop directly) but it isn't working either..**

```
$('button.page').on('click', function(e){
    var $userList = textArray($('#page-userlist').val().replace('http://lop/', '').split(/\n/));
    var $proxyList = textArray($('#page-proxylist').val().replace('http://', '').split(/\n/));
    var $question = $('#page-question').val();
    var data = {
        question: $question,
        users: $userList,
        proxies: $proxyList
    };
    var i = 0, p = 0, max = data.proxies.length, totalusers = data.users.length, percent = 0;
    $('#log').append("\n" + moment().calendar() + "\n");
    var progressbar = $('#page-progress');
    $.each(data.users, function(k, u){
        if(typeof(p) !== 'undefined' && p !== null && p > 0)
        {
            if(i % 10 == 0 && i > 1) p++;
            if(p == max) return false;
        }
        var proxy = data.proxies[p];
        percent = Math.round((i / totalusers) * 100);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Routing.generate('viral_admin_bot_page'),
            data: {question: $question, user: u, proxy: proxy},
            success: function(result) {
                $('#log').append("\nAtacado usuario " + u + " con proxy: " + proxy + "\n");
                $(progressbar).width(percent + "%");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                $('#log').append(error);
            }
        });


        i++;
    });
});
```

If i do `console.log(percent);` it is updating perfectly on each iteration, so I don't know where can be the problem.

Here is my code (without the ajax call because it isn't the problem) `http://jsfiddle.net/dvo1dm03/20/`

it will output to console the percentage, the objetive is to update the bar to the percentage completed in each loop, so it goes in "realtime" with loop.

Comment: Do you really have an element with the ID `-progress` (starting with a hyphen)  ?

Comment: sorry i was refractoring items in my code and it messed up, code updated (exact code but with correct ID, same problem of course)

Comment: And the mentioned console log, did you place that inside the success function as well.

Comment: Yes, it isn't in the code because it was a test, but it was, and also placed before the ajax call to make sure everything worked, and it did but not with progress bar width :S

Comment: When you send multiple AJAX request, there's no predicting the order that the responses will come back, they may not be in the same order as the requests.

Comment: In the fiddle the width is set, but probably not as you want it to. Do you want it to slowly increase from 0 to 100% ? Your code is setting it instantly to 100%.

Comment: @user1381537 I've updated your fiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/dvo1dm03/3/), is this how you want it to work?

Comment: @Barmar I tried to put the code before ajax request so it will update for sure on each loop, but didn't work.

caeth I want to increase +1% for each iteration, so it starts with 0% and end up with 100% when loop finish

Comment: The loop doesn't wait for the AJAX requests to finish, they run asynchronously.

Comment: @barman if I remove the AJAX call (or comment it) it doesn't work either, so I don't think the problem is the ajax call...

Comment: @barman Oh I missreaded your comment, that's interesting. Didn't noticed that it worked asynchronously, is there a way to make it synchronous? So loop must wat until ajax finished to begin next iterate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's how to do it asynchrounously.

```
var speed = 75;
var number_of_calls_returned = 0;  // add number_of_calls_returned++ in your ajax success function
var number_of_total_calls;
var loaded = false;

function processUserData(){
    if( number_of_calls_returned < number_of_total_calls){
        setTimeout(function(){processUserData();}, 200);
    }
    else{
        //received all data
        // set progressbar to 100% width
        loaded = true;
        $("#page-progress").animate({width: "100%"},500);
        $("#page-proxylist").val("Received data");
    }
}

function updateProgress(percent, obj){
    setTimeout(function(x){
        if(!loaded)
        $(obj).width(x + "%");
    }, percent*speed, percent);  
}


$('button.page').on('click', function (e) {
    var $userList = textArray($('#page-userlist').val().replace('http://lop/', '').split(/\n/));
    var $proxyList = textArray($('#page-proxylist').val().replace('http://', '').split(/\n/));
    var $question = $('#page-question').val();
    var data = {
        question: $question,
        users: $userList,
        proxies: $proxyList
    };
    var i = 0,
        p = 0,
        max = data.proxies.length,
        totalusers = data.users.length,
        percent = 0;
    //$('#log').append("\n" + moment().calendar() + "\n");
    var progressbar = $('#page-progress');

    number_of_total_calls = totalusers;
    $.each(data.users, function (k, u) {
        if (typeof (p) !== 'undefined' && p !== null && p > 0) {
            if (i % 10 == 0 && i > 1) p++;
            if (p == max) return false;
        }
        var proxy = data.proxies[p];
        percent = (i / totalusers) * 100;  //much smoother if not int
        updateProgress(percent, progressbar);
        i++;
        // simulate ajax call
        setTimeout(function(){number_of_calls_returned++;}, Math.random()*2000);
    });

    //callback function
    setTimeout(function(){processUserData();}, 200);  
});

var textArray = function (lines) {
    var texts = []
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        // only push this line if it contains a non whitespace character.
        if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
            texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
        }
    }

    return texts;
}
```

Check it out here! [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvo1dm03/34/) (really cool!)

Comment: I tried but it updates the bar after loop has finished, I mean, I see the animation perfectly but it is still animating when loop has ended time ago... Here's another jsFiddle with my code, which outputs to console what value should have the bar in that moment: http://jsfiddle.net/dvo1dm03/20/

Comment: @user1381537 Problem is you either have do it like this or make the ajax calls synchronous. You can try add `async: false` in your ajax calls, and use `$(progressbar).width(percent + "%");` in your success function.

Comment: Using `async: false` inside ajax, doesn't update the bar, it just get my interface freezed.

Comment: @user1381537 You can go with my original way, call a function with setTimeout and end of onclick function, and in that function wait for ajax queries. Try this out, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvo1dm03/32/)

Comment: @user1381537 you must take a look at the fiddle now (link updated in my answer)

Comment: Working like a charm!! I just needed to add some changes as the bar wasn't updating properly, if you check the new fiddle you will see the changes, now the bar updates EXACTLY when an ajax call is finished, otherwise it won't update :D http://jsfiddle.net/dvo1dm03/38/

Comment: Fiddle doesn't really work with your exact code, but i can figure how by looking at code, btw this percent = Math.round((number_of_calls_returned / number_of_total_calls) * 100); can be changed to percent = (number_of_calls_returned / number_of_total_calls) * 100); for a smoother progressbar.

Comment: Fiddle doesn't work with my code because of the ajax call yeah. Thanks for the percentage tip, I will use it as it auto sets 100% when finished so I don't need to bother about the rounded 100% :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is cause by the fact that you have a closure for your success function and every success function shares the same `percent` variable. You can fix it like this:

```
success: function(percent, result) {
    $('#log').append("\nAtacado usuario " + u + " con proxy: " + proxy + "\n");
    $(progressbar).width(percent + "%");
}.bind(percent),
```

Where you'll need to [shim bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) in older browsers, or like this, which is a little uglier, but should work everywhere without a shim:

```
success: (function(percent) { return function(result) {
    $('#log').append("\nAtacado usuario " + u + " con proxy: " + proxy + "\n");
    $(progressbar).width(percent + "%");
}; }( percent ),
```

Comment: if I use that code, which seems to be a good solution, I have this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : bots:454` that line is `error: function(error) {` the problem is with the comma after `( percent ),` maybe a typo? removing parenthesis from `(function(percent)...)` seems to fix it but progress bar goes crazy, loop finishes and bar gets random widths XD

Answer (score 0):

if what you want is to increase the update bar with each success of AJAX calls I'd suggest an easier solution (I've simplified the js code for clarity's sake):

```
$('button').click(function (e) {
    var i = 0,
        cont = 0,
        totalusers = 100,
        percent = 0;
    var progressbar = $('#page-progress');

    for (; i < totalusers; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                question: 'something',
                user: 1,
                proxy: 2
            },
            success: function (result) {
                cont += 1;
                percent = Math.round((cont / totalusers) * 100);
                progressbar.width(percent + "%");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $('#log').append(error);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

You can see it in action in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvo1dm03/37/).

Hope this helps or at least give you some ideas.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to make a recommendation of trying to make a self contained example that doesn't rely on the post so that it is easier for you or us to solve the problem

As well, you can console log elements so you could try logging the progressbar element, percent and the response of the ajax request

(This code is to replace the javascript sections of the fiddler)

```
var i = 0;
moveProgress();
function moveProgress(){
    if(i < 10000)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#page-progress').width((i / 1000) * 100); 
              moveProgress();
        },2);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The reason that it wasn't working was because the loop ran so fast that it was loaded by the time the script loaded it, the timeout allows you to delay the execution a bit(Though not necessarily recommended to use because of potential threading issues.

Comment: Great answer. Give this guy 1kg onions! :P

Comment: I think you shouldn't have posted this as an answer neither as a comment... But as you wished, here's a fiddle with the same procedure as my code but simplified, as you can see isn't working neither http://jsfiddle.net/dvo1dm03/

Comment: By the way, the problem isn't the ajax call as i tried without ajax and isn't working. Everything is going as needed and 100% working BUT the progress bar

Comment: In the fiddle it goes to 100% because nothing is rendered until the script finishes. You can never see intermediate states while a Javascript loop is running, unless you pause with something like `alert()` or `confirm()`.

Answer (score -1):

Update the progress bar using setTimeout method.

it will wait for some time and then update the width of progressbar.

```
myVar = setTimeout("javascript function",milliseconds);
```

Thanks,
Ganesh Shirsat